# Safe saddles for men's health

Tags: safety, saddle, health

As a continuation to [Why is it important to have good saddles?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/4400/why-is-it-important-to-have-good-saddles/4401#4401) I would like to know: Are there non-expensive saddles that are safe for men's health that you can advise.

A slightly different question, are there saddles that are safe for men with urology problems? For example, this is what I found in the mentioned question.

> Fortunately, there are several types of seats that can help alleviate that pressure and prevent injury. Look for seats with a split saddle, or one with a space in the area that would normally press into the perineum.

This means that there are such saddles, but can you mention any models?

Comment: I know a (formerly) avid cyclist who had several prostate surgeries.  The last few years he rode (before giving it up) he used a sling saddle.  But his doc advised him to give up cycling entirely.

Comment: This amounts to a request for medical advice, which is fine by me, but I guess that leads to another question: Is there a doctor in the house? These guys are bikers but maybe one of them is a biking doctor.

Comment: In general, requests for a list of products aren't a good fit for the site's format. Would you consider rephrasing to be more about what to look for in saddles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ISM](http://www.ismseat.com/) makes saddles that reduce pressure on the perineum and according to their [Marketing Material](http://www.ismseat.com/technology) is better for riding and having adequate blood flow.  All of their models have no nose to the saddle, so the rider sits further forward on the seat, removing the pressure area that frequently occurs with saddles.

I ride them on all of my bikes and have had no issues after switching to them with pressure and pain in the perineum area.

Answer (score 2):

No saddles exist which are unsafe for mens' health. What exists are saddles which do not fit particular bodies and, most importantly, misconfigured saddles and bad riding postures which can give a man some health issues.

Comment: thank you for the question, but could you mention any mention for someone with urological problem?

Comment: @user10756 The problem is that there is not *the* saddle for a certain problem. There are only some saddles or saddle forms that fit your needs and such that don't. Some of them are designed to address some special problems but that does not mean that they will fit you by default. If you know where your problems are you can boil down the number of candidates (e.g. by forms that don't fit you at all).

Answer (score 1):

There are several different makers and models that are designed to be comfortable and safe for men. However, if you have known urogenital issues, then I would get with your doctor and go through some of the available models and see which one he/she would recommend.

Once you have recommendations, then I would find a bike shop that lets you trial saddles for a short basis, as saddle fit and comfort are highly unique from individual to individual.